# Error 500 on $.connection.hub.start().done()

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr, signalr-service

Inside my existing application the get request to http://localhost:xxx/signalr/negotiate returns a 500 which I am unable to get more information about to find the actual cause

I have tried creating a brand new MVC project and setting up SignalR - this works.

I have tried using the sample projects and configuring to use my signalr service and these work too.

In both the diagnostic tools and the app insights portal I can't see any more information on what is causing this error 500

Nor does the dev tools in chrome give me more information

Its lengthy, but the best I can track down is a log from IISExpress which has the following error leading my to think its something to do with permissions/access that is being enforced by my application but I'm stuck as for where to start looking.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>3</Level>
  <Opcode>16</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-04-11T09:01:02.344Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000052-0004-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="18156" ThreadID="13096"/>
  <Computer>DESKTOP-SQ9UCSB</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000052-0004-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">__DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_ed612830-d174-4c74-ba1f-93c69902f2c6</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">4</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpReason">Internal Server Error</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"></Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">AUTHORIZE_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="ErrorCode">The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Tom

---

For reference, this is the code I'm using

The hub is a basic setup with only one function

```cs
public void Send(string messageText)
{
    Clients.All.broadcastMessage(messageText);
}
```

In my setup.cs I've followed the basic implementation but I've added some extra debugging (not that its helping!)

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new ErrorHandlingPipelineModule());
            app.MapAzureSignalR("/AzureSignalr", this.GetType().FullName, new HubConfiguration()
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                EnableJSONP = true
            });
            GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
        }

        private class ErrorHandlingPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule
        {
            protected override void OnIncomingError(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, IHubIncomingInvokerContext invokerContext)
            {
                throw exceptionContext.Error;
            }
        }
```

Lastly in my html file again I've followed the basic implementation but I've also tried explicitly setting the url and added more debugging again.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/AzureSignalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var messages = $.connection.myHub;

            messages.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
                alert(message);
            };

            $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:57690/AzureSignalr';
            $.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function () {
                console.log('We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.')
            });
            $.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
                console.log('SignalR error: ' + error)
            });
            $.connection.hub.start().done();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the solutions to this now, with credit to another question here;
[Azure SignalR Service Connection is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039861/azure-signalr-service-connection-is-not-active)

I altered my startup.cs to be the following;

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            app.MapAzureSignalR("/AzureSignalrPath", this.GetType().FullName, new HubConfiguration());
        }
    }
```

The important factor was the SecurityProtocol